# ROS Android Turtlebot Error

Tags: turtlebot, android-core, turtlebot-apps, android-teleop, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally built the teleop app for turtlebot by Kazuto Murase. I bringup the turtlebot locally, then compile the app onto my android device. Once i type in my turtlebot's IP address and hit connect, this error shows up on my turtlebot. Any ideas whats going on?

```
    [WARN] [WallTime: 1380244307.279967] Could not process inbound connection: request from [/start_app]: md5sums do not match: [874c7bc77072181994bed643cfd4d8d5] vs. [07c2c0d81a44b3d573187630fa526c81]{'message_definition': '# Name of the app to launch\nstring name\nRemapping[] remappings\n---\n# true ifapp started, false otherwise\nbool started\n# classifying start success/failure, see ErrorCodes.msg\nint32 error_code\n# human friendly string for debugging (usually upon error)\nstring message\n# Namespace where the app interface can be found\nstring app_namespace\n', 'service': '/turtlebot/start_app', 'callerid': '/start_app', 'md5sum': '874c7bc77072181994bed643cfd4d8d5', 'persistent': '1', 'type': 'rocon_app_manager_msgs/StartApp'}
[WARN] [WallTime: 1380244309.017550] Could not process inbound connection: request from [/stop_app]: md5sums do not match: [1f94f0ff0fc0fde186f728634f98a3cb] vs. [57711838d4a1faddc5043a742845018b]{'message_definition': '---\n# true if app stopped, false otherwise\nbool stopped\n# classifying start success/failure, see ErrorCodes.msg\nint32 error_code\n# human friendly string for debugging (usually upon error)\nstring message\n\n', 'service': '/turtlebot/stop_app', 'callerid': '/stop_app', 'md5sum': '1f94f0ff0fc0fde186f728634f98a3cb', 'persistent': '1', 'type': 'rocon_app_manager_msgs/StopApp'}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83661/ros-android-turtlebot-error/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-04**:
Please state the versions of OS and code (ROS, android apps) you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The kazuto apps were for groovy. Looks like you're running hydro on the turtlebot.

See http://wiki.ros.org/android for more information (specifically you want to build android_apps from github).

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0